# WInUI 3.0 Desktop - Crash on exception when try to navigate

Tags: c#, winui-3

I want to change frame, but I get this exception:

[image: Exception]

Navigation:

```
Frame rootFrame = new Frame();
rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(ScoreWindow), null, new EntranceNavigationTransitionInfo());
```

Exception appears on constructor:

```
        public ScoreWindow()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            results = new List<Result>();
            playerList = new();
            LoadData();
            var _resultsView = ConvertToView();
            sfDataGrid.ItemsSource = _resultsView;
        }
```

Thanks for answers in advance and happy holidays!

P.S. Thanks to Raymond, I detected this message:

```
WinUI: Error creating second Desktop Window on the current process. No more than one Desktop Window is allowed per process.
```

There is another question: how to change current frame to other? I mean, I have login view, user logged in successfully and want to see data/other things.

Comment: This is a stowed exception. You'll want to dig into the parameters to see what the underlying exception is. There may be clues in the Output window: Often the stowed exception is logged to the debug channel.

Comment: @RaymondChen I got it. It gives message: "WinUI: Error creating second Desktop Window on the current process. No more than one Desktop Window is allowed per process.". But, how will I change my window to other?

Comment: To change what is in a frame, navigate it,. But you can't create a new ScoreWindow. You'll have to reuse the frame from your other window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little break, I understood what I did wrong. There is a way how to navigate between pages.

Rule #1: In WinUI, you have only one active window, and it's MainWindow. Always. If you want to change layout, you have to use Frames.

In MainWindow.xaml, you write this:

```
    <Grid>
        <Frame x:Name="mainFrame"/>
    </Grid>
```

Element "Frame" give ability to navigate between pages.

Then switch to MainWindow.xaml.cs and in constructor have to be something like this:

```
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            mainFrame.Navigate(typeof(NameOfYourPage));
        }
```

It will immediately activate your page.

Then, if you want to navigate from page to page, write in control of page this:

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(NameOfYourPage), null, new EntranceNavigationTransitionInfo());
```

The third parameter is animation, but I didn't notice changes.

More information you can find here:

[Tutorial about navigation](https://wellsb.com/csharp/learn/your-first-winui3-app-windows11)

[Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.frame.navigate?view=winui-3.0)